# Internet Explorer doesn't support the HREF property for DOM elements?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, href, ie8-compatibility-mode

The code below works fine in Chrome and FireFox, but gives an error in when I try to set the href property in IE8.  The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method".  Here's the code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("linkToGoogle")
if (elem)
{
    elem.href = "https://www.google.com/"
    elem.target = "_blank";
}
```

I did some Web searches and there seems to be some issues with IE8 having something called "Compatibility View".  I don't remember ever setting that in my IE8 instance and I am certainly not using the Meta tag to request it.  Even so, I still need to be compatible with it.  Is there a quick solution to this?  Note, I also tried replacing the element's outerHTML content instead and that got the same error message.

Comment: That looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("linkToGoogle")
if (elem)
{
    elem.setAttribute('href',"https://www.google.com/");
    elem.setAttribute('target ',"_blank");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I just tried your solution and got the same error.

Comment: The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method" and the object that is located by getElementById("linkToGoole") is this: <a NAME="linkToGoogle" ID="linkToGoogle" href="javascript:alert('Your search query is empty.');"><img SRC="/images/link_to_google.gif" HSPACE="5px" VSPACE="5px" alt="Go to Google"/ title="Open the current search in the Google."></a>.  As you can see, until the visitor does a search they get the alert().  After they do a search, the link changes to passing the search on to Google.  But it doesn't work in IE.   Works fine in Chrome and FireFox.